# Unable to activate GRASS GIS provider

Tags: qgis

I am unable to access GRASS tools from QGIS.

I still get the same message when I activate the GRASS GIS provider extension :

```
OSError: [WinError 87] Paramètre incorrect 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\grassprovider\Grass7AlgorithmProvider.py", line 105, in loadAlgorithms
    version = Grass7Utils.installedVersion(True)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\grassprovider\Grass7Utils.py", line 114, in installedVersion
    with subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1436, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 87] Paramètre incorrect


Version de Python : 3.9.18 (heads/master:c290dc6, Jan 14 2024, 01:36:02) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 
Version de QGIS : 3.28.15-Firenze Firenze, 252ad49ddc 

Chemin Python :
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/ldesc/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/ldesc/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass83\etc\python
C:\Users\ldesc\Documents
C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python39.zip
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib
C:\OSGeo4W\bin
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/ldesc/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```

I tried fresh installs of the latest version, the long-term version, and now using OSGEO4W, suppressing AppData and other remaining folders.

I was expecting fresh installs to solve the dependencies, especially because the two different QGIS versions relies on different versions of GRASS.

However, nothing solved my problem.

Did someone already solved this problem?

Thank you very much!
Lucas

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution : COMODO protection software was containing all the GRASS related files... I cleaned the containing list in COMODO and GRASS plugin worked!